# SpringDataRest @RepositoryEventHandler not running when Controller is added

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have an event handler that runs perfectly fine on a repository. However once I add a controller into the mix and call the repository method directly, the EventHandler seems to be skipped over.

Has anyone encountered this "issue"? If so, what can I do to get the event handler to start running again?

Answer (score 8):

So you expect that your event handler is called when you use a custom controller. I think this expectation is false. The event handler is just called when spring data rests `RepositoryEntityController` is in control. It is not an entity event listener on JPA level.

What you could do is call the event handler manually. The spring-data-rest `RepositoryEventHandler` is a using normal spring application events. So your controller could implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` and publish one of the spring-data-rest application events. These are all subclasses of `org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.RepositoryEvent`

```
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new AfterCreateEvent(myEntity));
```

See the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events) for details.

Comment: Based on the available documentation, I don't think it's unreasonable for a new user to make this assumption if their controller is annotated with `@RepositoryRestController`.   It is, afterall, called `@RepositoryEventHandler`, not `@RepositoryControllerEventHandler`

Comment: @Snekse that might be the case - I can just tell you that it is not the case - but I detailed my answer a bit with information on how you could still make use of the `RepositoryEventHandler` in your custom controller.

Comment: As Mathias said, you can publish your own events.  Make sure you're handling them all (Before, After, Create, Save, List, Delete). Here is another good example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37616850/378151 

In our project we have a MyEntityValidator that we call from the controller and the Repo event handler also calls.