# @RepositoryEventHandler events stop with @RepositoryRestController

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-rest

When I create a `@RepositoryRestController` for an entity, the associated `@RepositoryEventHandler` methods are not triggered in Spring Data REST via Spring Boot 1.4.0.M3 (also Spring Boot 1.3.5) -- is this a bug, or *as designed*?

I have an `Account` entity with an `@RepositoryEventHandler`:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Account.class)
public class AccountEventBridge {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleBeforeCreate(Account account){
        log.info("Before create " + account);
    }

    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void handleAfterCreate(Account account){
        log.info("Created " + account);
    }
}
```

which trigger as they should when I POST:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 
  -d '{"name":"aaa", "owner":{"email":"aaa@1010","password":"snap"}}'
  http://localhost:8080/api/accounts
```

unless I add a `@RepositoryRestController`:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class AccountRespositoryRestController {

    private final AccountRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public AccountRespositoryRestController(AccountRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/accounts")
    public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(
        @RequestBody Account account,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        // ...
        Account entity = this.repository.save(account);
        return assembler.toResource(entity);
    }
}
```

When I comment out the `@RepositoryRestController` annotation, the `@RepositoryEventHandler` methods trigger, again.

It seems like these should behave independently since they operate a two different conceptual layers within Spring Data REST -- or am I misunderstanding something?

If this is intentional, it's unfortunate -- I'll have to implement all HTTP methods to create the events myself for any entity with an `@RepositoryRestController`. Is that really the intent?

Comment: _"since they operate a two different layers"_ Not according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events): _"events that the REST exporter emits"_. REST exporter, not database. It's a feature of Spring Data REST, not Spring Data.

Comment: Yes, @zeroflagL, `@RepositoryEventHandler` and `@RepositoryRestController` are both part of _Spring Data REST_ module; my note above refers to two different layers within _SDR_.

Comment: While I consider these two different _conceptual layers_, @zeroflagL, apparently _SDR_ agrees with your interpretation. ;-) See my solution below for the details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's *as implemented*. :-)

The methods defined in a `@RepositoryRestController` implementation replace the methods in the default [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java) which publish `@RepositoryEventHandler` events.

But it's easy to add these events making the `@RepositoryRestControll` a `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` implementation and publishing the events like the default `RepositoryEntityController` implementation:

```
@Slf4j
@RepositoryRestController
@AllArgConstructor
public class AccountRespositoryRestController 
    implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    private final AccountRepository repository;
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(
        ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/accounts")
    public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(
        @RequestBody Account account,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        // ...
        publisher.publishEvent(new BeforeCreateEvent(account));
        Account entity = this.repository.save(account);
        publisher.publishEvent(new AfterCreateEvent(entity));

        return assembler.toResource(entity);
    }
}
```

You can also inject the publisher without making the class `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`:

```
@Slf4j
@RepositoryRestController
@AllArgConstructor
public class AccountRespositoryRestController {

    private final AccountRepository repository;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/accounts")
    public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(
        @RequestBody Account account,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        // ...
        publisher.publishEvent(new BeforeCreateEvent(account));
        Account entity = this.repository.save(account);
        publisher.publishEvent(new AfterCreateEvent(entity));

        return assembler.toResource(entity);
    }
}
```