# @RepositoryEventHandler only invoked via HTTP - why?

Tags: spring-data-rest

when I use a @RepositoryEventHandler then its methods are only invoked when the call into the repository comes in via HTTP.

Any reason why? OK, it is called Spring Data REST, but wouldn't it be VERY useful to invoke the handler too, when I call my Repo directly, not via HTTP?

Any way to invoke the handler when called directly (some magic AOP-stuff)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that the different persistence mechanisms covered by the different Spring Data modules already ship with event mechanisms. Depending on the one you use you now get a different mechanism to use.

Unfortunately this can't be unified as e.g. with JPA not all persistence operations need to go through the repository in the first place, as JPA automatically flushes all changes that were made to an attached instance on `EntityManager` flush. In this case even AOP on the repository instance doesn't help.

So you're basically left with two choices:

- The events exposed by Spring Data REST for all repositories (as we basically don't make use of the automatic change tracking in JPA).
- The store specific event mechanisms that will make sure that the persistence mechanism exposes events as documented.

Comment: What do you mean with "The events exposed by Spring Data REST for all repositories"?  

"The store specific event mechanisms": Since I use JPA: Do you mean the lifecyle events like @PrePersist etc?

Comment: "…for all repositories" — for all repositories independent of their backing persistence technology. "… JPA" — yes.

Comment: You mean AbstractRepositoryEventListener? Is this called when I invioke a Repository directly, not via HTTP?  
  
@PrePersist & Co: But here I am not allowed to call a EntityManager method, e.g. when I want to create other Entities when an Entity is created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the solution I put below from other stackoverflow questions would seen as acceptable by @Olivier-drotbohm, but from:

[SpringDataRest @RepositoryEventHandler not running when Controller is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210903/springdatarest-repositoryeventhandler-not-running-when-controller-is-added)

and

[@RepositoryEventHandler events stop with @RepositoryRestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603231/repositoryeventhandler-events-stop-with-repositoryrestcontroller)

you could inject/autowire the "ApplicationEventPublisher" and fire the BeforeCreateEvent/AfterCreateEvent manually to trigger the RepositoryEventHandler.

This is not a perfect solution, but I hope it is good enough for you (and we tested it: it works).

Comment: Also, be careful with this approach: events are fired, but you have no guarantee that any operation made on the entity in the event handler is executed before the code that is after the firing of the event. For instance: if you fire a onBeforeCreate on a "Item" entity and then save it, and in the handler of the onBeforeCreate you change the title of the item, it will most probably not be saved with the changed title. Firing events is asynchronous, whereas calls to repository through REST are linked to EventHandlers with AOP.